# Accessing data by using a vector of pointers inside a function from the same class C++

Tags: c++, function, pointers, vector

here is my problem: I'm working with two different classes A and B. Class A contains a vector of pointers to objects of type B and I want to use this vector in a function myfunc, which is a member of A. Here is an example

```
class B {

public:

int x, y;

float z;

// other class members...

};



class A {

public:

// other class members...

vector <B*> myvect;

float myfunc() {


for(size_t i = 0; i < myvect.size(); ++i) cout << myvect[i] -> x << endl;

// rest of the code...

return (some float)

}

};
```

The program does not compile. It returns an error saying that B is undefined type. It only compiles if I comment out the cout statement. I searched the internet and tried several things, like declaring i as an iterator and dereferencing the iterator, but nothing worked. Any ideas what's wrong with this code?

Comment: did you include the h file for B in A?

Comment: The code you've posted compiles (once I remove the spurious `*` characters in the declaration of `myvect`, add the missing headers, and fix the return statement). Does your real code include the definition of `B` before the definition of `myfunc()`?

Comment: Hi, what you read before was a typing error in the display because Stack Overflow seems to work with special characters, I've now corrected it. This is the syntax i'm using and still no result.

Comment: The definition of B comes before A. By including the h file of B in a i get more than 100 errors

Comment: @MikeSeymour it compiles because the classes aren't separated into files.

Answer (score 1):

You can `#include "B.h"` inside `A.h` or, the more correct way, have a forward declaration for `class B` before the definition of `A` and move the implementation outside of the header:

```
//B.h
class B
{
//...
};

//A.h
class B; //forward declaration
class A
{
    //...
    vector <B*> myvect;  // <- correct syntax
    float myfunc();      // only declaration
    //...
};

//A.cpp
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

//...
float A::myfunc() { //implementation
   for(size_t i = 0; i < myvect.size(); ++i) cout << myvect[i] -> x << endl;
   // rest of the code...
   return (some float)
}
//..
```

Comment: Just a small nitpick: you don't want to have `using namespace std` in a header file, so in A.h **vector** should probably be **std::vector**

Answer (score 0):

The compilation error stems from the fact that in your `cout` statement you are **dereferencing** the pointer to B. And to do that, the compiler must have a definition of class B available at this point.

In other words, the code like this

```
pointerToB->x
```

is valid only if you have `#include "B.h"` prior to that point.

So, you may either do it in `A.h`, or, to avoid this extra coupling (and also to avoid large header files), you may want to move such pieces with pointer dereferencing into `A.cpp` and forward-declare class B in `A.h`, just [as Luchian suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10178273/5722863).

Answer (score -1):

I'd try adding brackets first:

```
cout << myvect[i] -> x << endl;
```

to this:

```
cout << ((myvect[i]) -> x) << endl;
```

I'll put it at good odds that it's just something simple like that, and that cout is trying to "take" the B* object first, prior to the arrow operator.  If that's not it, please post the compiler error messages.

Comment: error C2227: left of '->x' must point to class/struct/union/generic type

Comment: Hi, Sorry, I forgot to reply. I did, but it didn't work either :( Same errors as above.

Comment: the implementation of the function outside the class, float A::myfunc() . I put it in the file of main(), above the main function.

Comment: I did, sorry I'm quite new to Stack Overflow ;)

Comment: @user1298521 you didn't, and still haven't.